# Citizens Bank: What counts as a 'qualified online bill payment'?

Tags: online-payment

I am hoping to get the $200 bonus through [this offer](http://www.citizensbank.com/200/). One requirement is that I must post "three qualified online bill payments".

My question is: What counts as one such bill payment? Does it have to be some company (e.g. my cell phone bill or utilities bill)? Or could it be to some private individual (e.g. a friend of mine)?

The fine print seems to hint that the latter is possible:

"Qualified bill payments must be initiated through the bank’s online banking bill payment service and be made to three different payees and for a recipient other than someone in your household."

Comment: The quote seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly as described in the quote. Pick any three "bills" not owed to family members.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided, it seems like it can be any payee, as long as the check isn't delivered to your own address.

From my experience using three other banks with similar requirements (2 bill pays / month), as long as you initiate the bill pay from the bank's website, it should be okay.

You can pay anything that you could pay with a check, such as utilities, rent, loan payments and credit card payments. Payments to friends and individuals is fine also, but it's a little bit of a hassle since you have to tell them what you're doing and ask for the money back, unless you really do owe them money.

After three bills have cleared, you can send a secured message through their website asking if the requirement for the bonus has been met. I prefer secured messages to a phone call because it leaves a permanent record.